# I need to run an exe on a site directly from it's database

Tags: javascript, php, html, exe

I have an exe that I need to run on a site, I have access to it's database, I need to upload it and run it directly from the site, so how can I make it execute like in windows and how do I make it to show on the site(javascript?)

Comment: This question is too broad. What have you tried ? Do you control the plateform on which the application will be run ? What do you mean by "have access to its database" ? Will the .exe make calls to the database ? What do you mean by "run it from a database" ? Do you want to store the exe in the database ? What technology do you use for your server-side code ? You said javascript but what exactly ? angular ? please add more information.

Comment: "I have an exe that I need to run on a site". In that case log into the server via RDP using your administrator credentials, copy the exe there and execute it as required. If you're talking about uploading the file and via PHP and then getting the server to execute it...well firstly **don't** write code to do this...it opens up a massive security hole in the site, even if only certain users can do the upload, it's a bad idea. I'm also unsure what a database has to do with it. You can't run an executable from within a database (I'm not even sure what that phrase even means...)

Comment: also, why are you doing this ? This sound like a bit security and design flaw ... what is this .exe meant to do ?

Comment: The other thing which occurs to me is that this is some sort of question about executing files maliciously on a site which you don't control...I really hope that's not the case. If the site _does_ have such a vulnerability which would allow this to take place, the responsible thing to do would be to inform the owner of the site so that they can fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment this question isn't valid on this site but I'd like to point something out before it gets deleted :

Storing a whole .exe in a database sounds a bit odd. If you really need to then I guess you could store a byte array in the database and then re-write the exe to the filesystem from the byte array.

A better solution would be to store the .exe on the filesystem right away and only store the path to the executable in the database.